# Detected an object of type "Timestamp" that doesn't match the expected instance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm wondering why is the Timestamp object is not working as I expect?

It works in test environment (I use Mocha), but throws error when it has been deployed.

**index.ts**

```
import { Timestamp, QuerySnapshot } from "@google-cloud/firestore";
....

async someFunction() {
   let col = firestore.collection("mycollection");
   let now = Timestamp.now();
   let twentyMinsAgo = Timestamp.fromMillis(now.toMillis() - (1200 * 1000));

   return col
      .where('LastEdited', '>=', twentyMinsAgo) //This throws error
      .get()
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Argument "value" is not a valid QueryValue. 
Detected an object of type "Timestamp" that doesn't match the expected instance. 
Please ensure that the Firestore types you are using are from the same NPM package.
      at Validator.(anonymous function).err [as isQueryValue] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:99:27)
      at CollectionReference.where (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:940:25)
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
   ....
   "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.16.0",
   "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
   "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now I get it why it throws an error. Because I import Firestore object separately, whereas I should just use Firestore object from Firebase Admin SDK.

What I changed:

1. remove "@google-cloud/firestore" dependency from **package.json**
2. Use admin.firestore.Timestamp object.

**index.ts**

```
async someFunction() {
   let col = firestore.collection("mycollection");
   let now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
   let twentyMinsAgo = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(now.toMillis() - (1200 * 1000));

   col.where('LastEdited', '>=', twentyMinsAgo) //Now ok
      .get()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

when using firebase admin avoid importing and using any of the client side package directly

so instead of

```
 import * as admin  from "firebase-admin";
 import firebase from "firebase/app";

 admin.firestore().collection("name").set({
       date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
})
```

use this instead

```
 import * as admin  from "firebase-admin";

 admin.firestore().collection("name").set({
       date: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
})
```

##### 2022 EDIT:

> For newer version of Firebase ^10.0.2; Timestamp can be imported directly

```js
import * as admin  from "firebase-admin";
import { Timestamp } from "firebase-admin/firestore"; 
 
admin.firestore().collection("name").set({
   date: Timestamp.now(),
})
```

Comment: Is there a well-known pattern to re-use Firestore code that uses Timestamp from a common dependency codebase?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in how the client side and server side packages format `Timestamp` for some reason.

**client**

```js
import { Timestamp } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

```json
[

    "LastEdited": {
        "seconds": 1709272799,
        "nanoseconds": 999000000
    }
]
```

**server**

```js
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
```

```json
[

    "LastEdited": {
        "_seconds": 1709272799,
        "_nanoseconds": 999000000
    }
]
```

**client solution when querying from server**

manually create the `Timestamp` from the return

```js
const timestamp = new Timestamp(data.LastEdited._seconds, data.LastEdited._nanoseconds);
```