# Module '@google-cloud/firestore' is not listed as dependency in package.json

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using TypeScript for writing my **Firebase Cloud Functions**. In my code I need to refer firestore data types like CollectionReference, QuerySnapshot etc. For example:

```
export const Employee: CollectionReference = admin.firestore().collection('Master/Admin/Employees');
or
async function convertToCsv(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot[])
```

To use these types in my code, I am using the following lines on the top of the file (.ts):

```
import { QueryDocumentSnapshot, Timestamp, Query, CollectionReference } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
```

**This code works fine when I run firebase function locally on my PC** using:

> firebase serve --only functions

But when I try to deploy the same code on my firebase server, I get the following tslint error and code deployment fails.

```
Module '@google-cloud/firestore' is not listed as dependency in package.json
```

if I add the dependency in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    ...
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "~1.0.1"
  },
```

My functions get deployed, but on execution, I get the following error:

```
Error: Argument "value" is not a valid QueryValue. Detected an object of type "Timestamp" that doesn't match the expected instance. Please ensure that the Firestore types you are using are from the same NPM package.
    at Validator.(anonymous function).err [as isQueryValue] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:93:27)
    at Query.where (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:916:25)
    at /user_code/lib/services/reports/index.js:53:22
```

The compiled java script line where it fails is (see **):

```
const firestore_1 = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
let query = collection
                    .where('divisionCode', '==', divisionCode)
                    **.where('zzLastUpdateOn', '>=', firestore_1.Timestamp.fromDate(startDate))**
                    .where('zzLastUpdateOn', '<=', firestore_1.Timestamp.fromDate(endDate))
                    .where('zzIsDeleted', '==', false);
```

I really have no clue what to do here, please help. Please know I am very new to TypeScript and JavaScript world.

> Please know that other functions in a same project, where i am adding value into Timestamp field is working fine. And this function also works fine in Cloud Function simulation mode on desktop (local host).

Your help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The following change in my code has helped to clear the problem.

Instead of using the "**Timestamp**", I am now using "**firestore.Timestamp**". This change has helped me move further in my development.

Now my code looks like this:

TypeScript Code:

```
let query: Query = collection
                .where(...)
                .where('zzLastUpdateOn', '>=', firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(startDate))
                .where('zzLastUpdateOn', '<=', firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(endDate))
                .where(...);
```

And Generated Java Script Code:

```
let query = collection
                    .where(...)
                    .where('zzLastUpdateOn', '>=', firebase_admin_1.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(startDate))
                    .where('zzLastUpdateOn', '<=', firebase_admin_1.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(endDate))
                    .where(...);
```

My sugestion is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52609487/6943737 query.

Comment: This probably shouldn't be an answer. It should probably be an edit of the original question, since the problem still isn't resolved.